# Generate numbers based on existing records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have not been able to figure out best way to do this.

[image: Sample data]

As the screenshot above shows record. I am trying to figure out a way to auto create/insert record based on existing. For example, in the image i have record that has "Begin" and "End". There is 0-24. I would like the procedure or something to create records as follow:

```
Begin       End  
0           24  
1           24       
2           24  
....
```

Everything else will stay same, it will create records automatically. What would be the best way to tackle this?

Comment: One solution is using a cursor.

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` function on a table with sufficient number of rows:

```
SELECT numbers.number AS [Begin], yourtable.[End]
FROM yourtable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS number
    FROM sys.all_objects
) AS numbers ON number BETWEEN [Begin] AND [End]
```

Answer (score 0):

I Would suggest an function to get the incremented value and use it during the insertion.
(use appropriate data types you have used in parameter and return type of function)
sql is like :

```
      CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNextBeginValue ()
      RETURNS BIGINT
      AS
      BEGIN
      DECLARE @RETVAL BIGINT

        select @RETVAL = IsNull(Max(Convert(BIGINT,BEGIN))+1 ,1) from TableName

      RETURN @RETVAL 
      END
```

and while inserting, use like

```
       insert into TableName(begin,....) values(dbo.GetNextBeginNumber(),.....)
```